# Are entry points required for non JavaScript assets in web pack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader, extract-text-plugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

The only way I have successfully had webpack generate a non JavaScript file is to include an `entry` for the primary asset. The problem is, webpack is generating a `.js` file based on this asset as well, which is unnecessary. Is this the correct way of working with non JavaScript assets in a webpack config?

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const outputDir = 'build';
const extractStylus = new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/screen.css');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/js/index.js',
    print: './src/js/print.js',
    stylus: './src/stylus/screen.styl'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: extractStylus.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [extractStylus],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `${outputDir}/js`)
  }
};
```

The specific line in question is part of the `entry` object:

```
stylus: './src/stylus/screen.styl'
```

Without that line, nothing is generated, but with that line, the expected `.css` as well as a `stylus.bundle.js` file are generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what the `entry` property does in a webpack config:

> An entry point indicates which module webpack should use to begin building out its **internal dependency graph**. After entering the entry point, webpack will figure out which other modules and libraries that entry point depends on (directly and indirectly).
>
> Every dependency is then processed and outputted into files called bundles, which we'll discuss more in the next section.
>
> [[source](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry), emphasis mine]

Without specifying an `entry`, webpack would not know where to look for your files; even if the dependency graph was not directional (which it is), you need to point webpack to at least one point of the graph.

The minor problem of having a JS file generated even though you are only processing assets is a consequence of how webpack generally is used – as an asset manager / compiler for some application logic written in JS. So, in theory, if you needed to use the compiled assets via NodeJS style `require`s, you'd use the generated `stylus.bundle.js`.